# Why I can't see my objects in chrome console in react?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, google-chrome

I want to see my non react component class in my chrome console

```js
class Developer {
   constructor(firstName, lastName) {
      this.firstName = firstName;
      this.lastName = lastName;
   }

   getName() {
      return this.firstName + ' ' + this.lastName;
   }
}

let x = new Developer('Bob', 'Russ');

console.log(x.getName())
console.log(x)
```

I use this code in my App.js and Index.js and a new js file
i see the result of my code (Bob Russ) in chrome console
but when i write x or Developer i cant see my object hierarchy in console

Comment: It's not clear what you're asking, the code snippet surely works when executed in the console. It prints "Bob Russ" as expected. BTW, how's this related to react?

Comment: What you are probably looking for is in `__proto__`; which is not shown here; the "getName" will be on the object `prototype` not in the object itself.

Comment: I mean when i write x in google console i expect that it show me the object hierarchy but it say "x is not defined"  but as you see i have x in my file that is a Developer instance

Comment: @AminFadaee the snippet you provided work as expected. Not sure what you mean by "google console". What are you expecting to see exactly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's because your react variables are encapsulated, and not part of the global scope. If you need to access an object from the chrome console, for some reason, you need to make a reference to it on the "window" object.

```
let x = new Developer('Bob', 'Russ');
window.x = x;
```

Now you should be able to access x from the console.